# Why this test with Rackunit does not work?

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, racket

I am using Racket and Dr. Racket for educational purposes.

I am trying to understand the [values](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._values%29%29) built-in function.

When I call values with the following input I get this output:

```
> (values 'this 'and-this 'and-that)
'this
'and-this
'and-that
```

Why does this test fail?

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit racket/trace)

(check-equal? (values 'this 'and-this 'and-that) 'this 'and-this 'and-that)
```

Comment: Just as an aside, whenever I've had a problem and decided to use `values` to solve it, I wound up with two problems and rewriting the code to provide a list or a string seems to wind up requiring less and simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `values` is returning [multiple values](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=values#%28part._values-model%29), and `check-equal?` can't handle that, it expects exactly two values to compare. For instance, this would work because we're dealing with only two values:

```
(check-equal? (values 42) 42)
```

Try a different approach, let's say we first unpack the multiple values and put them in a list:

```
(check-equal?
 (let-values ([(a b c) (values 'this 'and-this 'and-that)])
   (list a b c))
 '(this and-this and-that))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert multiple values to a list and then compare it to expected values:

```scm
(define-syntax values->list
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr) 
     (call-with-values (lambda () expr) 
                       list))))

(check-equal? (values->list (values 'this 'and-this 'and-that))
              (list 'this 'and-this 'and-that))
```

`values` is very special. It ties with `call-with-values`. Practically it works pretty much the same as `list` and `apply` but without making cons being created in between. Thus **its just an optimization**. In an implementation using stack it would return values on the stack and  `call-with-values` would just apply with the same frame it got from applying the thunk.

I do think Common Lisp version is more useful as it allows multiple value procedures to be used in single value situations with only the first value being used. In Scheme dialects you need to use `call-with-values` or a macro or procedure that uses it in order to handle multiple values, which is less flexible but perhaps can do other calls slightly more effiecent.